# Pass loop data to jquery ajax model

Tags: php, jquery

I have a loop of data from my **Lesson** table.
When I click Specific lessons link it opens a Model.
I want to pass specific Lesson_id to Videos form but jquery repeats the first Index of data(first lesson's id).

I have used both an **Id** and **Class** but the results are the same.
here is my code.

```
     <a  class="btn btn-info add_video" data-id="<?php $lesson->id ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Video</a>
```

And this is Jquery Function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#add_video_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
       var link = $('.add_video').attr('data-id');
       alert(link);
    });

});
```

Comment: try `var link = $(this).attr('data-id');` instead of `var link = $('.add_video').attr('data-id');`

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="" id="add_video_form">`
my form didn't has a data-id

Comment: Share the proper code of your form.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are getting value of link with class name. May it get duplicate or used in you html structure more than one time.

I suggest you to check the length of add_video class with **$('.add_video').length;**

If It is returning more that 1, you have got the error. It needs to return 1. In above case. Also, you can try to check length with **$('#add_video_form .add_video').length;** 
If it returns 1, then you can get the same value with **var link = $('#add_video_form .add_video').data('id');** or you can use Id as well to retrieve the specific element.

Comment: my form is seperate from the loop.
`<a  class="btn btn-info add_video" data-id="<?php $lesson->id ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Video</a>`
This is the code thats inside the loop.
But my form is a model which is not in the loop.